# Pattern matching from file in perl

Tags: linux, perl, grep

I want to use a grep in perl, but I am confused here.
What I want to do is, there is one file like-

```
this is abctemp1
this is temp2
this is temp3x
this is abctemp1
```

Now, I want to extract unique words from this file using pattern 'temp', i.e., 'abctemp1, temp2, temp3x'and want to store it in an array. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict; use warnings;

my (@array, %seen);
/(\w*temp\w*)/ && !$seen{$1}++ && push @array, $1 while <DATA>;
print "$_\n" for @array;

__DATA__
this is abctemp1
this is temp2
this is temp3x
this is abctemp1
```

Answer (score 1):

Words for every line are in `@F`, and are pushed into `@r` if contain `temp` and are not seen yet,

```
perl -anE 'push @r, grep { /temp/ && !$s{$_}++ } @F}{ say for @r' file
```